# bootstrap modal from button inside slickgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, slickgrid

I am trying to call a modal from within a button inside a slickgrid. I have tried using.

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Clicking on the button inside the grid will not display my second modal.
 I plan on having another grid inside this new modal. I have looked at perhaps using a latest version of bootstrap because i thought that may be what was causing the issue but it has not made a difference. Here is my fiddle [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Domt301/q1cyrnm5/) [image: undefined function]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option:
http://jsfiddle.net/sh1fcygt/1/

Launch the modal though data attributes in the '.show-report' button.

```
   function reportFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
        return "<button class='show-report' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>show</button>";}
```

Comment the modal show in subscribe event.

```
grid.onClick.subscribe(function(e,args) {
 if ($(e.target).hasClass('show-report')) {    
     //$('#myModal').modal('show');
```